# SPF is soft failing for GMail

Tags: spf

I have a GMail account for a custom domain name. I added a SPF record per their instructions, which just says to add a TXT record:

`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`

I did this and has been updated correctly. However, when I do a SPF check on a valid email address on numerous sites I get a "Soft Fail".

For example, when testing here: http://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester

Why is this?

I think this might be because I am inputting the incorrect ip address, as I entered the server ip address and perhaps they are expecting Google's ip address, but that's just me guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to answer my own question.

Turns out the problem was as I expected, in that the IP address needs to be where the email is being sent from (i.e. Google's server).

To find the ip address see this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764

Essentially just run: `nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8` on your terminal.

I think there is quite a few IP addresses you can use. I just used: `64.18.0.0` and SPF policy check tool passes without a problem!

However, it is better to use a real validator by sending an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` or `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`.

Comment: Are you saying you changed the SPF to something different then what you posted? I'm confused.

Comment: No. The SPF record is perfectly fine. It just when you are checking if your SPF record is valid using a service like spf-policy-checker, you need to use the IP address of where the mail was sent from (I.e. Google for GMail)

Comment: Ok, I understand, but why not use a real validator and send an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` or `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`? Then you will get a real result, without having to figure out what IP you're sending from.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think those are better.